# Discovering fake links in e-mail messages using Java

Tags: java, html, email, smtp, spam

The problem is - fake links in e-mails, which are sent by scammers. They look like:

```
<a href="http://www.ebrug.eu/lnfo/power-SEIIER/portal/" target=
"_blank">http://pages.ebay.de/aboutebay/contact.html</a>
```

Is there any simple already known solution to discover such fake links using Java? I'm thinking about using regex expressions, filter both links, check if they valid and then to comapare them. Later, if it is fake message, SMTP server will refuse to accept it.

Comment: While the comparing is interesting, how will you handle the valid case of URLs that pass through some marketing company and then forward to the actual company? The domains will not match in that case.

Comment: My argument is that honest author of an e-mail message always puts the same URLs at "href" part and link description part (of course, description could be not an URL). But this method would filter some annoying/stupid messages.